# Fetch Post params sent empty- React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

i'm using post to send some params, but all i got is empty data, my function look like this:

```
got = () => {


    fetch('****', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        adress: " nnn-tka ",
        CIN: "bg2222",
        name:"kdkdkd",

      })
    })

      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("repooooonse")
        console.log(res)
        console.log("*********success***********")


      })
      .done();
  }*/
```

anyone have any idea what's wrong?.
thank you

Comment: Could you provide us more information about the backend side? fetch request looks fine ( unless you are literally putting asterisk in url then its not )

Comment: i will suggest to use axios

Comment: Give us some more details? It might be the case the back-end is returning empty for the inputs passed

Comment: the problem is that the back-end side its not me that works on it, all i know is that we're using odoo ERP.